# Is this a smart draw offer?

Tags: analysis, sicilian-defense, blunder, time-management, online-blitz

```
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2018.12.27"]
[White "SergioRamos2"]
[Black "SmojLee"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[ECO "B57"]
[WhiteElo "1640"]
[BlackElo "2175"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[EndTime "10:48:30 PST"]
[Termination "Game drawn by agreement"]
[CurrentPosition "8/3kb1p1/7p/6p1/8/3K4/6PP/4R3 b - - 1 54"]
[FEN ""]

1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.Nc3 Bd7 4.Bc4 Nc6 5.O-O Nf6 6.d4 cxd4 7.Nxd4 a6 8.f4 Qb6 9.Be3 Ng4 10.Nd5 Nxe3 11.Nxe3 Nxd4 12.Kh1 Nc6 13.Qe2 e6 14.Rab1 Be7 15.c3 Qc7 16.a4 O-O 17.Bd3 Rfd8 18.Rf3 Rac8 19.Rh3 h6 20.Rf1 Bf8 21.Rg3 Ne7 22.Qh5 Ng6 23.f5 exf5 24.exf5 Qc5 25.b4 Qe5 26.Ng4 Qd5 27.c4 Rxc4 28.Bxc4 Qxc4 29.Rd1 Qe4 30.fxg6 fxg6 31.Qd5+ Qxd5 32.Rxd5 Bxa4 33.Kg1 Bc6 34.Rd4 d5 35.Ne5 Bd6 36.Nxc6 bxc6 37.Ra3 c5 38.Rd1 c4 39.Kf1 Bxb4 40.Rxa6 Kf7 41.Ra4 Be7 42.Ra5 Ke6 43.Re1+ Kf6 44.Rd1 Rc8 45.Raxd5 c3 46.Ra5 g5 47.Ke2 Kf7 48.Ra7 Ke6 49.Kd3 Kf7 50.Rf1+ Ke8 51.Re1 Rd8+ 52.Kxc3 Rd7 53.Rxd7 Kxd7 54.Kd3  1/2-1/2
```

This is a game I had with black and I was doing well with time and position but it came down to one move that made me lose!  Luckily my opponent is time trouble so he had to offer a draw. Was it smart of me to accept it since he was up by +1 and he only had 40 seconds left? I would appreciate if someone could analyse the game to see what went wrong,   thank you!

Comment: What was the time control?

Comment: 10 minutes Blitz

Comment: 10 minutes blitz explains the fact that white just blundered a piece in the opening and didn't resign after that. But don't expect anyone to go to great lenghts to analyze this; blitz games are rarely interesting to analyze, especially if they contain serious blunders like this one.

Comment: I thought 10 minutes is rapid.

Comment: @Akavall According to Wikipedia, 10 min/game seems to be the cut-off between blitz and rapid that official organizations use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first thought was that black had won a piece by move 12, and should have been able to win without getting into such heavy complications. For instance, a move like 15...Qc7? is just a bad move from a strategic standpoint. It's not necessarily losing or anything, but black doesn't know for sure where the queen is supposed to go, whereas black knows for sure that the king should get to safety. This is a good rule of thumb: begin by dealing with the pieces you know where they are going before manoeuvring with the pieces for which it's unclear where they stand better.

Basically what went wrong for black in this game is not a one-move mistake in my opinion. Black went on with a standard plan in the open sicilian, ignoring the fact that white was preparing a kingside attack. This made everything very awkward in the end, and once white's attack was actually picking up steam it was already unneccessarily difficult for black to respond properly. I'm sure that one could make detailed remarks on many of the moves played in this game, but noting that this was a 10-minute blitz game I see little reason to make a detailed analysis of this game. One suggestion I would make for black in this game is that black should've played 11...Qxd4 instead of 11...Nxd4. The reason is that black is already a full piece up at this point, and if the queens are traded white is just doomed, since there will be no talk about kingside counterplay then.

As for the question about the draw offer, black has zero winning chances in the final position. In general, it's never a bad idea to accept a draw offer in a worse position even if your opponent is low on time, and this is no exception to that rule. 40 seconds is enough for white not to blunder a rook, and realistically black is the only one actually risking anything by playing on. But in the end I think the position is drawn and I see no good try for white to actually make any progress.

Answer (score 4):

> Was it smart of me to accept it since he was up by +1 and he only had 40 seconds left

The final position was a **dead draw**, so there was nothing wrong taking the draw offer. However, you would probably win the game by time if you had continue (assuming you had more than 40 seconds on the clock and no increment). Moved your king aimlessly, and pushed for h5-h4 to reset 50-move counter. It would have been a battle on mouse reaction, not chess anymore.

It was a wise decision by position, but unwise if you really wanted a win at all costs.

Comment: I had about 2 minutes with no increment and I was thinking of flagging him but I just accepted the draw since I don't wanna waste energy in an unrated game